# Destructure single object into an array of multiple objects

Tags: javascript

I have the following array with on single object in it.

`[{"IP_Address":"33.4.160.5","originEmailAddress":"james@willis.com"}]`

I want to destructure it and put it into this format, a two-element array of objects:

`[{"IP_Address: "33.4.160.5"},{"originEmailAddress": "james@willis.com"}]`

What would be the most efficient way of doing this? I know how to get it back into the same format, like this:

```
let keys = Object.keys(test[0]);
let values = Object.values(test[0]);

const merged = keys.reduce((obj, key, index) => ({ ...obj, [key]: values[index] }), {});
```

but cannot figure out how to get it to reduce into an array of two objects. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you need the result for? I never found that format (array of distinct single-key objects) to be useful anywhere.

Comment: I'm building a decentralized application on Ethereum where each of these parameters needs to be sent to a separate smart contract. The transaction arguments accept a single object with one key-value pair. It cuts out a processing step I would normally do on the receiving end, but cannot do in a Solidity smart contract

Answer (score 3):

There you go:

```js
const before = [{"IP_Address":"33.4.160.5","originEmailAddress":"james@willis.com"}];

const after = Object.keys(before[0]).map(entry => ({ [entry]: before[0][entry] }));

console.log(after);
```

Comment: legendary, thanks... long long day. So basically you're creating the array of the keys, mapping those to their corresponding values in the before object? What is tripping me up is the usage of the key (entry) to retrieve both the key and value

Comment: uuhh im such a slower typer I was literally just about to paste this same thing as an answer hahah!! good stuff!

Answer (score 2):

I'd write

```
Object.entries(object).map(entry => Object.fromEntries([entry]))
```

Comment: Don't you need to get the first item from the array first? `([object]) => Object.entries(object).map(entry => Object.fromEntries([entry])))`

Comment: @BlueWater86 I simplified `arrayOfOneObject[0]` to `object`, yes